# Usage of Articles

Tags: grammar, articles

I found this line on official [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18752?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US).

> Click the Launchpad icon in the Dock, hold down **an** app’s icon until
>   all the icons begin to jiggle, then click **an** app’s delete button .

Don't you think the second instance of **an** should be replaced by **the**? Am I missing out something here? And even if the sentence means to say to that any other app can be deleted, isn't it better to use **any** instead of an?

Comment: What's happening here is that there are two steps.  In the first one, you hold down any app (i.e. "an app") and the icons all start to jiggle.  At that point, all the icons have an X in the corner, which you can click on to delete the app.  You can click on the X in any app, not just the app you originally clicked on.  You can even repeat this action to remove multiple apps.  (Thus "click an app".)  If it said "click the app," it would mean you could only remove the one you originally selected.  But since they all jiggle, you can remove any app, not just the one you originally selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the linked support page. I have included another sentence from the same page.

> Click the Launchpad icon in the Dock, hold down **an** app’s icon until all the icons begin to jiggle, then click **an** app’s delete button . If you later want **the** app, you can reinstall it from the Mac App Store.

a/an = indefinite article

the = definite article

... hold down **an** app's icon - *You can hold down **any** **(non-specific)** app's icon to delete any app that you wish to*

... If you later want **the** app - *You can install **the** **(specific)** app that you just deleted*

See [How to use Articles?](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/)